# Python reinstallation --enable-unicode=ucs4 and lxml undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeLatin1

Tags: software-installation, python, xml

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04. I needed for my new django project to compile python with `./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4` option. I reinstalled python with ucs4.

Now when I'm trying to run scrapy spider, I get an error like this:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeLatin1
```

I tried to reinstall python again but got an error:

```
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

Then I tried to reinstall libxml, but that throws an error too:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Scrapy reinstallation doesn't help.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score -2):

I solved it.

I deleted manually the directory containing the python dist which causes the error.

```
sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

Then I reinstalled python, scrapy and django manually from a source.

Comment: So, you deleted the version you compiled? Could you elaborate on the second part of your answer? Most Ubuntu users will not need to reinstall python and are likely to damage their system by doing so in unsafe ways. So it would be really good if you could be more specific about what exactly you did (and why it was needed in your situation) etc